# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on shutdown / reboot D630

Tags: dell

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell 630 laptop.
Shutdown & Reboot hangs on the Ubuntu splash screen

[image: Ubuntu Splash Screen]

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Joeri

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the hang on reboot / shutdown had to do with the wireless drivers which were not installed.

Installed the wireless drivers with these commands: 
sudo apt-get remove --purge ndiswrapper*
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

Then reboot.

Comment: Worked for me to remove the hang at shutdown/reboot, but to install the WiFi firmware I had to `apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`. The WiFi then worked perfectly on my Dell Latitude D800.